# css - background image not showing or actual image got distorted

Tags: html, css, image

I need to set background image for a list of `<img src="image.jpg"/>`. I could only get background images displayed using this css:

```
img{
    background:url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:240px;
    display:block;
}
```

However, some of my `<img src="image.jpg"/>` do not have the same image proportion as 300:240, they got distorted. Is there another way to show background and not getting image distorted?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set fixed width and height, try to set like this

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try preserving the aspect ratio in the CSS

```
img{
    /* Preserve aspet ratio */
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

For more information, visit this link: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

If this still gives you problems then consider sticking to images of similar resolutions (Those that work).